# How to execute producerB if and only if producerA doesn't throw an error?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I am trying to work with the below scenario
I have two producers A and B.
`producerB` should execute only when `producerA` is executed successfully and also if `producerA` throws error, handle the error and stop there. So I tried something like this.

```
producerA.flatMapError {
    // handle error and stop right here 
}.then(producerB).startWithResult { 
    // ...
}
```

Looks like `producerB` executes even if `producerA` throws error.
Please help me how can I make it work with my scenario.

Comment: Map / flatMap returns an array. What do you mean if it returns error ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is what, exactly, you mean with "does not throw an error".

The sequence of Events on a `Signal`/`SignalProducer` has a [precisely defined semantic](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/Documentation/APIContracts.md#the-event-contract)

Theres an arbitrary number of `Value` (from 0 - x) Events, followed, eventually, by a `completed`, `failed` or `interrupted` Event. After that there's no more events.

Generally you can say that **most** operators only operate on `value` events and immediately propagate `failed` events (without operating on them). If you're not sure in for a specific operator, take a look at the documentation of that operator which is very clear about the behaviour for failure events.

---

So one way to understand the question is to say *when `producerA` completes successfully (after an arbitrary number of `value` Events), then start `producerB` and if `producerA` sends a `failed` Event, then don't.*

In that case, the `then` operator is exactly what you need. It will start `producerB` as soon as `producerA` completes, but **not** if `producerA` fails!

```
producerA.then(producerB)
  .start(Signal.Observer(value: { value in
    print("Value \(value)")
  }, failed: {error in
    print("Error \(error)")
  }))
```

Note, that you **dont** want to use the `flatMapError` here because that would (depending on how your error handling in the block looks) convert `failed` events to `value` Events which would trigger `producerB` eventually.

---

Another way to understand the question is to say *each event on `producerA` that is not an error should trigger `producerB` once*

In that case, you would use `flatMap` on the events of `producerA` to return a `producerB` for each event on `producerA`. Note here, again, `flatMap` propagates a `failed` event immediately, so a `failed` event on `producerA` will cause the whole chain to fail **without** execution of `producerB`

```
producerA.flatMap(.concat) { _ in return producerB }
  .start(Signal.Observer(value: { value in
    print("Value \(value)")
  }, failed: {error in
    print("Error \(error)")
  }))
```

Comment: Good answer. I find that a good way to think about it is that `flatMapError` is basically used to catch an error. In fact, it [used to be called catch](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/commit/e0c266320ba160944eda894210ece7121216f174). So you shouldn't use it if you actually want the error to terminate the signal chain. I would add that if you don't want the entire chain terminated on error then you can just put the `flatMapError` *after* `then.(producerB)`.

Comment: @MeXx i see some problem here in the first approach. Let's say first producer doesn't producer error and second producer produces the error, it is printing the value and it never goes to failed block.

Comment: @coolly, after `producerA` sends its value, is it completing? `producerB` will only start once `producerA` completes. You should use the second approach with `flatMap` if you want `producerB` to start when `producerA` sends a value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
func scenario() -> SignalProducer<MyValueType, MyErrorType> {
        return SignalProducer { observer, _ in
            producerA.startWithResult({ (res) in
                switch res {
                case .success(let value):
                    observer.send(value: value)
                    observer.sendCompleted()
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)//handle your error here
                    observer.send(error: err)
                }
            })

        }.then(producerB)
    }

scenario().start()
```

You create a custom SignalProducer and define the desired behaviour by telling the observer to operate based on your scenario.